# Encrypted Storage Exception

Tags: codenameone

When I start my application, it is giving me below mentioned exception. I'm using encrypted storage class but don't know why this exception is there even i am not accessing any storage class at this time. 
Please guide.

> [EDT] 0:0:0,32 - Exception: java.io.EOFException - null
>   java.io.EOFException  at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)   at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)     at
>
> java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)     at
>
> com.codename1.io.Util.readObject(Util.java:536)   at
>   com.codename1.io.Storage.readObject(Storage.java:261)     at
>   com.codename1.io.Preferences.get(Preferences.java:83)     at
>   com.codename1.io.Preferences.get(Preferences.java:298)    at
>   com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.initEDT(CodenameOneImplementation.java:235)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:951)   at
>   com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)    at
>   com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)

Comment: The stack trace is missing some lines, can you post the rest?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have preferences from a previously unencrypted session that the system is trying to decrypt. To prevent such a collision in the future try using [setPreferencesLocation](http://codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Preferences.html#setPreferencesLocation-java.lang.String-) after encrypting. This will abandon the old preferences and force encryption on the new data.